# Backoffice target names in SAP Hybris

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I want to create access rights for the backoffice through an ImpEx. The problem is that I can't find all the names of Components.

Is there any website or any file where I can read out the target names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that access rights should be organized by user groups and targeting root item types as much as possible.

You can list all item types from the backoffice/hmc under the type section or with the following FSQL query:

```
SELECT a.code AS itemtype 
FROM ({{SELECT {i:pk} AS pk, {c:code} AS code FROM {Item AS i},{ComposedType AS c} 
WHERE {i:itemtype}={c:pk}}}) a GROUP BY a.code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use System > Types in backoffice.